# Serializing and deserializing a List<List<object>> with BinaryFormatter

Tags: c#, serialization, stream, deserialization, binaryformatter

Let's say I have

```
List<object> mainList = new List<object>();
```

And it contains

```
List<string> stringList = new List<string();
List<CustomClass> custList = new List<CustomClass>();
mainList.Add(stringList);
mainList.Add(custList);
```

To serialize

```
Stream stream;
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
formatter.Serialize(stream, mainList);
```

To deserialize

```
Stream stream = (Stream)o;
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
List<object> retrievedList = (List<object>)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
```

At this point, I receive an error that the stream read (deserialization) reached the end of the stream without retrieving a value.

Do I need to specify something besides...

```
[Serializable]
public class CustomClass { .... }
```

in the custom class to make this work? Can I not deserialize a List> that contains different type of object every time?

I tried

```
IList list = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(custClassList[0]))
```

and tried to send and receive this, but got the same issue.

I can however serialize and deserialize a specified type or List, but I really need it to be dynamic.

Comment: without `Serializable` attribute or implementing `ISerializable` interface you can't serialize a Type with `BinaryFormatter`

Comment: is this line just a typo? `List<object> retrievedList = formatter.Serialize(stream);` or is this from your code? ;)

Comment: `List<object> retrievedList = formatter.Serialize(stream);` should be `List<object> retrievedList = (List<object>)formatter.Deserialize(stream);` in order to compile. I assume it is a typo. Correct it

Comment: what Sriram Sakthivel suggested ;) but your code would not even compile if you had it like posted in your question so I think you meant `Deserialize` anyway (with a cast of course)

Comment: you are **still** calling `Serialize`...

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Ok, fixed. Now what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, BinaryFormatter is a joke. It works in some cases, but will fail in almost identical scenarios for unknown reasons.

The best and superior alternative to BinaryFormatter is the third-party library **protobuf-net** (https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net), developed by [Marc Gravel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell).

This beauty solved all the problems I was having in one pass. It's much easier to set up and reacts more perfectly to complex, custom classes.

I should also mention that it's faster, in the terms of de/serialization.

Comment: "usually" faster. I've found if you've got large arrays of primitives (eg int[]) then BinaryFormatter is faster than Protobuf.Net

Comment: Protobuf-net (at least the .net port) was created by Marc Gravell, not google.  It just happens to be hosted on google.code.

Answer (score 1):

In order to fix the issue that causes the error **"stream read (deserialization) reached the end of the stream "**, the stream position needs to reset to 0 as follows...

```
stream.Position = 0;
```

> Do I need to specify something besides...
>
> [Serializable] public class CustomClass { .... }

Nope...That should be good for what you are doing.

> in the custom class to make this work? Can I not deserialize a List>
>   that contains different type of object every time?

You should be able to serialize any object.

Comment: I've tried that. I'm reading from a NamedPipeServerStream that's been written to by a NamedPipeClientStream, which will give me an error saying that it "can't seek."